# Is this a valid form of typedef struct and if so, what does it mean?

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

Working with a piece of code right now that features declarations of the form:

```
typedef PACKED(struct) 
{

// some stuff in here

} struct_name;
```

now...PACKED is a macro on our part.  What the heck does this syntax mean?  **I don't understand the use of parenthesis.**  This is not compiling, so I'm guessing this is probably incorrect. Is this close to some other valid syntax, or is it just nonsense?

If it is almost valid..*how is this code actually supposed to be written and what is it supposed to mean?*

The only form of typedef struct I've seen and can find online is:

```
typedef struct
{
 // some stuff in here
} struct_name;
```

Solved:  All I needed to realize was that struct was a parameter in a macro function. Thanks!

Comment: To know how to fix this, you'll have to tell us exactly which compiler you're using, and which compiler the code originally used if it's different.

Comment: You should, at least, provide the definition of the macro. It is legal or illegal depending on the macro, legal for `#define PACKED(x) x` but illegal for `#define PACKED( x ) And you thought this would compile...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually something in all caps is a macro. In this case it's probably supposed to decorate the struct declaration with the syntax for creating a packed structure, which will vary based on the compiler used.

Chances are you're completely missing the definition of the PACKED macro.

Comment: using parenthesis like that is valid though?  What is the point of the parenthesis?  I can't find anything of this form online.

Comment: @Casey macros can take parameters using parenthesis. Example: `#define DOUBLE(X) (2*(X))`

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers provide the functionality to specify how structures should be stored in memory. It's rarely used, but `packed` usually means `*have this structure occupy the least space possible, even at a loss of speed in accessing its members*`.

Given that your code doesn't compile, I'd say `PACKED` was most likely a macro now lost, or a compiler-specific keyword not available in the one you're using.

Answer (score 1):

With that syntax, PACKED has to be a macro.

Probably referring to some manner of struct alignment

```
 __attribute__(packed, aligned(1)) 

#pragma pack(push,1)
//...

#pragma pack(pop)
```

though hard for us to tell you, as opposed to the reverse :))

Comment: So a semi-plausible version of the macro might be: `#ifdef SomePlatform / #define PACKED(x) x / #else / #define PACKED(x) x __attribute__(packed, aligned(1)) / #endif`, so that where the compiler recognizes the attribute, it is (ab)used, and where it is not, it is not given.

Comment: yes, though silently ignoring an expectation of struct alignment would not be recommended.  I'd rather see #error when it wasn't supported.